# get method dosen't return a right result

Tags: android, asp.net, html

I'm tring to build a android client for a website, of which I have no control. I can only use httpwatch to detect the data flow and decide to use either `post` method or `get` mathod.

Here I come across a problem, after logining in the website, I click a button to load some data(the url in the browser dosen't change,name it url-1), it works well and the httpwatch tells it is using `get` method with a target url(a different one,name it url-2). If I paste the url(url-2) in the brower it returns to the login page without loading any data. I check the html source code and find the `iframe` tag, which may be used to realize local refresh.

In android, I use `httpclient` to do `post` or `get`, I can login in and keep a connection with the server, but I failed when tring to use `get` method to load some new data, it also returns the login page.

Why it works like this, is there any way to get the right answer？